# How to search with date using apache solr

Tags: php, solr4

i want to search data from solr like below

[image]
this is my two tables:

[image]

[image]

So how can i do this date search using solr....

**Edit**

Iam using SolrPhpClient for this.

This is fields from my schema.xml:

```
    <fields>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
   <field name="event_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="event_category_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="cat_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="event_sub_category_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="sub_cat_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="event_location" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="org_id" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
   <field name="org_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="event_city" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="multiple_tags" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

   <field name="multiple_start_dates" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

   <field name="event_twitter_url" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
   <field name="event_fb_url" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
   <field name="search_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <copyField source="event_name" dest="search_text" />
    <copyField source="cat_name" dest="search_text" />
    <copyField source="org_name" dest="search_text" />

    <copyField source="multiple_tags" dest="search_text" />

    <dynamicField name="*" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>
```

The following image is the solr admin with all queries:

[image]

So when i search `multiple_start_dates:2013-10-24T00:00:00Z` in `q` it returns `invalid date string` error......

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from schema it appears that you have not indexed date fields from your tables, once you index date fields like created and modified columns, you can make queries like these:

```
(created:[NOW-1MONTH TO NOW]) //for current month

(created:[NOW-3MONTH TO NOW-1MONTH]) //created within last three months but not in current month
```

and so on, do some experiment with other units of time and (+/-) operators, you will get desired queries.

Comment: ,i added and indexed data , that was successfully completed, but searching returns error

Comment: The query you are making is not a range query, try putting the value of input date in double quotes.

Comment: ok, so i just tried with this one `"multiple_start_dates:2013-10-24T00:00:00Z"` but it returns numFound:0....

Comment: This is because there are no such records in your index

Comment: now i changed to like this `multiple_start_dates:"2013-10-24T00:00:00Z"` then it works fine.....

Comment: the above query i just need to test the date are working, my actual need is in the first picture....

Comment: please look at my answer, just do some experiment with date units like day, hour, month week, year and +/- operators

Comment: i just tried `(multiple_start_dates:[NOW-1MONTH TO NOW])` but it takes all datas.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39256/discussion-between-kichu-and-sumit)

Comment: chat servers are blocked in my office :(